# Wait for window.onload event using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, window, webdriver, wait, loaded

I need a solution how to wait until the web page is fully loaded. And exactly after that, waiting no longer, I need to perform actions with a web page: get URL of loaded page, check cookie, click `<a>` elements so on

I use the following code before work with loaded page:

```
IWait<IWebDriver> wait=new WebDriverWait(drv, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.00));                
wait.Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)drv).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
```

But this code does not wait in 100% cases until full load of a page in Chrome,  and does not work in Internet Explorer!

Could you please offer better solution

Thanks for an answer in advance!

Comment: May be I'm very late to the party, but I found the same problem, and I solved it by using a small extension, which just creates and adds an elements with a known id inside the window.onload function which is injected by the extension as a content script, and in the webdriverwait, we can wait for the presence of this element by id

Answer (score 1):

document.readyState does not always return the actual status of page load completion. see if you can wait on a particular element on the page, perhaps which gets loaded last on the page.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm aware of such solution - for the situation when the structure of the page that will be loaded, is known. BUT the problem is that the structure of

Comment: the page that will be loaded is NOT KNOWN BEFOREHAND (I simulate user's click on the banner in which a number of advertised products is displayed, each particular time different ad).After the click on banner, the advertised product's page load. I need to somehow receive event 'window.onload' or 'document.ready', but currently I have no idea how to implement this.